# std::is_trivially_xxx which one imply another

Tags: c++, c++17

I have hard time to understand following concepts:

- is_trivially_copyable
- is_trivially_copy_assignable
- is_trivially_copy_constructible
- is_trivially_destructible
- is_trivially_move_assignable

Take for example `std::string_view`.

```
#include <string_view>

int main(){
    using sv = std::string_view;

//    static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<sv> );
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<sv> );
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<sv> );
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<sv> );
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<sv> );
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_move_assignable_v<sv> );
}
```

My question is which of these, imply others, so I can to less static_assert's in my code?

I know `is_trivial` imply all of these,

Note I am not interested in c-tors:

- is_trivially_constructible
- is_trivially_default_constructible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::is_trivially_copyable` covers the rest, though allows for the relevant methods to be deleted. It says:

> If T is a [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) type, provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

And requirements for [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) are:

> - Every copy constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every move constructor is trivial or deleted
> - Every copy assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - Every move assignment operator is trivial or deleted
> - at least one copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator is non-deleted
> - Trivial non-deleted destructor

You can even check [llvm implementation](https://llvm.org/doxygen/type__traits_8h_source.html).

This is related to the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

AFAIK rest of the test are basic and unrelated to each other in terms of logical implications.

Apart from tests you mention [`is_copy_assignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_copy_assignable) and `is_copy_constructible` (and possibly other "copy" versions) can be formulated in terms of no-copy tests e.g. [`is_assignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable). But this is something different, since checking for "copy" is just adding additional type constraint.

Comment: so basically test for std::is_trivially_copyable is enought?

Comment: and `std::is_trivially_copyable` imply `std::is_trivially_destructible` ?

Comment: Yea, sorry, I've misread original question and missed `is_trivially_copyable` I reformulated the answer nearly completely but it should be correct and answer your questions. So you are right with a nitpick that the method can be deleted.

Comment: The answer says this, but it deserves emphasizing:  `is_trivially_copyable_v` does not imply that something is `copy_constructible`, much less `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v`.  For example `struct A {A(const A&) = delete;};` is `is_trivially_copyable` but **not** `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v`!